# ehCache and Spring MVC Error with HIbernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, ehcache

I keep getting this error while setting up ehcache in Spring MVC.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheEvictionTask': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Below is my setup, and I am using hibernate 3.2.7.GA

```
<ehcache:config cache-manager="ehCacheManager">
    <ehcache:evict-expired-elements interval="60" />
</ehcache:config>

<beans:bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="configLocation"  value="/WEB-INF/spring/ehcache.xml"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
           <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.2</version>
           <type>pom</type>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>terracotta-releases</id>
            <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by using an exclude, so yes there was a clash issue.

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${org.hibernate.commons.annotations-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The zip file of ehcache-spring-annotations containing the dependencies, downloaded on the project web site, contains ehcache-core version 2.2.0. You're using 2.3.2. There might be an incompatibility between those versions.